# Shadow Catcher showing HDRI through it

Tags: hdri, shadowcatcher

I have a hdri, and a cube around my model for a flat background. But the shadow catcher under the model shows the hdri through it. Any way to stop this?

Comment: Suggest render the background as separate pass...

Comment: How do I do that? So far with trying layers, the shadow catcher still shows the hdri on it.